Nominate or Innominate?
got this question for my assignment. some of my friends are saying this is nominate contract specifically, a contract of agency. but i believe it to be an innominate contract of do ut facias. would like to get your input
Jo-Ann asked her close friend, Aissa, to buy some groceries for her in the supermarket. Was there a nominate contract entered into between Jo-Ann and Aissa? In the affirmative, what was it? Explain.
